# UPS Surepost TimeInTransit API

Tags: ups

We have had UPS Surepost enabled to our account and a MailerID assigned. However when making POST requests to UPS endpoint: https://onlinetools.ups.com/rest/TimeInTransit we do not get any UPS Surepost services in return. Do we need to add the MailerID to the request somewhere (we have tried with same response). I have tried to reach out to the UPS tech support for documentation and support with no success.

```html
{
   "Security":{
      "UsernameToken":{
         "Username":"XXXXXXXXX",
         "Password":"XXXXXXXXX"
      },
      "UPSServiceAccessToken":{
         "AccessLicenseNumber":"XXXXXXXXX"
      }
   },
   "TimeInTransitRequest":{
      "Request":{
         "RequestAction":""
      },
      "ShipFrom":{
         "Address":{
            "AddressLine":null,
            "City":"Las Vegas",
            "PostalCode":"89103",
            "CountryCode":"US",
            "ResidentialAddressIndicator":false
         }
      },
      "ShipTo":{
         "Address":{
            "AddressLine":"XXXXXXXXX",
            "City":"Las Vegas",
            "PostalCode":"89144",
            "CountryCode":"US",
            "ResidentialAddressIndicator":true
         }
      },
      "Pickup":{
         "Date":"20211118"
      },
      "InvoiceLineTotal":{
         "CurrencyCode":"USD",
         "MonetaryValue":"100"
      },
      "ShipmentWeight":{
         "UnitOfMeasurement":{
            "Code":"KGS",
            "Description":""
         },
         "Weight":"1"
      }
   }
}
```